# Identifiers for WebRTC's Statistics API

Tags: webrtc

Could anyone tell me which identifiers in WebRTC Statistics API are directly related to the quality of the experiences users have during connections?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of session. A videocall where many participants collaborate has different needs than an audio call where one talks any the others mainly listen.

In general the elements that impact the perceived quality are `packetsLost`, `jitter`, `currentRoundTripTime`, `framesDropped`, `pliCount`, `framesDropped`.

You should also consider that the bandwidth estimators adapt the bandwidth (and so the quality) based on the feedback from the other party.

If you search for "Quality of experience estimators for WebRTC" you'll find studies that use the above statistics to estimate the QoE.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the source code of https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector. There are many detectors that uses WebRTC Stats API to determine the overall quality of webrtc call. E.g. [InboundNetworkIssueDetector](https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector/blob/master/src/detectors/InboundNetworkIssueDetector.ts) demonstrates how to use jitter, jitterBufferDelay, packetLoss and many others stats params.